# Using AzureDevOps Rest Client library to delete an environment from a release definition

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm trying to determine how to delete an environment from a release definition using the client library. Is there a way to remove the environment without having to update the entire release definition?

The code snippet below illustrates what I'm trying to do.

Calls to `UpdateReleaseDefinitionAsync()` fail because the ReleaseDefinition object returned from the `GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync()` call does not contain the PreConditions for the environments. I'm not seeing an expand option to return this information in my call to `GetReleaseDefintionsAsync()`.

If possible, I would prefer to just be able to remove the intended environment without having to populate all of the properties of the `ReleaseDefinition` that aren't related to the `Environment` I wish to remove.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
var expandedDefinitions = _releaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync(_projectName, _targetReleaseDefinition.Name, expand: ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Environments | ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Artifacts | ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Triggers | ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Variables).Result;
var targetDefinition = expandedDefinitions.Where(d => d.Name == "TheDefinitionIWantToUpdate").First();

var targetEnvironment = targetDefinition.Environments.Where(e => e.Name == "TheEnvironmentIWantToRemove").First();

bool success = targetDefinition.Environments.Remove(targetEnvironment);

_targetReleaseDefinition = _releaseClient.UpdateReleaseDefinitionAsync(targetDefinition, _projectName).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to remove the environment without having to update the entire release definition?

No. The APIs for release definitions operate on the entire release definition. There is no API for manipulating only a single environment within a release definition.